# Launching an application from backround task in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I have a C# application based on the Sample Background Task demo code. It is running a task in the background every X minutes. I would like it to launch my application if certain conditions are true. I am not having any luck searching for things like "launch application from background task" on google I've tried rewording it in as many ways as I can think of but I am still getting no relevant results.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible for a background task to launch an application? and if so point me in the right direction to figure out how.

Comment: As I've tried it seems that *LaunchUriAsync* method is restricted in BTask, so handling uri activation won't help here. One idea is that you can send a toast message from the background and once user taps the toast, he is redirected to your app.

Comment: This app is meant to be used a bit more like a kiosk. There isn't a single User as there would be on a personal device. There may or may not be anyone actually interacting with the device at any given time so unfortunately I cannot rely on them having to tap anything.

Comment: As I can imagine the app that is fired every 30 minutes, then I'm glad there is no such an option. AFAIK there is no possiblity to open the app without user interactin (with public API). If you don't need user, and there will be no one, then what's the purpose of UI? Can't be the work done in BTask - a resource intensive task or other?

Comment: The purpose of the the UI is to attract people to the device, to get them to notice it and come start playing with it. Essentially I'm aiming for a more customized "Retial Mode" type application.

Comment: AFAIK that won't be possible - as I've written in the first comment.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

Control flow for apps is restricted for good reasons.
There is no way to launch any app without user interaction.

Only thing you could do is show a toast message that allows the user to go to your app if he so wishes.